# Get ASSOC array value by numeric index

Tags: php, arrays, database, codeigniter, associative-array

In all the examples of Codeigniter queries at https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html, I find that the name of the field must be known to get its value.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT title,name,body FROM table");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
  echo $row->title;
  echo $row->name;
  echo $row->body;
}
```

For example, if I want to get the `title`, I will perform `row->title`. Is there a way to get the `title` using an index e.g. like `$row[0]`?

Comment: it's object you cant use an object as array.

Answer (score 3):

Use `result_array` function returns the query result as a pure array

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT title,name,body FROM table");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    foreach($result as $res){
      echo $res['title'];
      echo $res['name'];
      echo $res['body'];
    }
```

if you want to access via index then use array_values:

```
    $result = $query->result_array();
    foreach($result as $res){
      $r = array_values($res);
      echo $r[0];
      echo $r[1];
      echo $r[2];
    }
```

Comment: -1 The OP wants to get the values by numeric index, not by the key name.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $result = $subject_code->result_array();
   foreach($result as $res){
   $r = array_values($res);
   print_r($r);
   }
?>
I applied the above code but in o/p index of each value is comming 0
o/p- Array ( [0] => 201 ) Array ( [0] => 202 ) Array ( [0] => 203 ) Array ( [0] => 204 ) Array ( [0] => 205 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more elegant way:

```
$data = $this->db->query("SELECT title,name,body FROM table")->result_array();

array_walk($data,function(&$row) {
    $row = array_values($row);
});
```

And you have $data array with numeric indexes.