# mysql_fetch_row in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

how to use mysql_fetch_row in codeigniter?
in php when i user mysql_fetch_row i will get result like this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,email FROM people WHERE id = '42'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; // 42
echo $row[1]; // the email value
```

i can get array with index in number type.

But when i use codeigniter like this code

```
$db=$this->load->database($_SESSION['DB'], TRUE);
        $q=$db->query("select ID, Name from mdashboard");
        foreach($q->result_array() as $d)
        {
            echo $d['ID'];
        }
```

i get array with index in string type.

can Codeigniter do like my first code?

Comment: **DON'T USE `mysql_query`**. Don't. Stop right there. Read the documentation on [accessing databases in CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/#database-reference). If you're getting errors, work through the problem and fix it. Don't give up and go back to an obsolete API. Maybe `$d` is not in the form you expect it to be. Find out what that contains before accessing it.

Comment: **USE** `mysqli` **OR** `pdo`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get ASSOC array value by numeric index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854774/get-assoc-array-value-by-numeric-index)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.use `row_array()` to get the matched result set in where condition.

```
$this->db->select('id,email');
$this->db->where('id',42);
$row = $this->db->get('people')->row_array();
echo $row['id']; // 42
echo $row['email']; // the email value
```

Comment: when i use row_array i must type code like $row['id'], not $row[0]

Comment: Oho yes sorry mistake.Try now.

Comment: in the point, i want get data with array in number index, not string index

Comment: You have an associative array.So need to use key as offset.You can not get value using index.

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter use mysql get result as array you can do that

```
use result_array() get result  or use row_array() get number
public function getBy($where = array(), $field = '*')
{
    $this->db->select($field);
    $query = $this->db->get_where($this->table_name, $where);
    if (!$query) {
        return array();
    }
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use codeigniter's `row` function instead of `mysql_fetch_row` :

```
$q=$db->query("SELECT id,email FROM people WHERE id = '42'");
$result= $q->row();
$result_array =  array_values((array)$result);
$email = $result_array[1];
```

Comment: how if the result more then 1 data?

Comment: edited my answer, with casting of the result to array.
`result_array[0]` is the id, `result_array[1]` is email.

Comment: if the result is more than one row use `q->result()`

Answer (score 0):

This may be help you

```
$this->db->from('people');
$this->db->select('id,email');
$this->db->where('id',42);
$result_array = $this->db->get();
$result=$result_array->row_array()
echo $row[0]; 
echo $row[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is custom function to get data as per your need.

```
function getData ( $news_id )
{
    $this->db->select('ID, Name');
    $this->db->from('mdashboard');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
       $row = $query->row_array();
       return $row;
    }
}
$result = getData();
echo $result['ID'];
```

NOTE : **DONT USE mysql_* function because they are depricated in newer version**